# Wordpress Woocommerce - Subtotal and totals don't match

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I tried this code to get different tax classes based on cart total, but it doesn't get updated on the "Totals" columns.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'big_apple_get_tax_class', 1, 2 );

function big_apple_get_tax_class( $tax_class, $product ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < 1000 )
        $tax_class = 'Tax-5%';
    elseif ( WC()->cart->subtotal >= 1000 )
        $tax_class = 'Tax-12%';
    return $tax_class;
```

[image: image showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Why would it match ?

An extra Shipping charge on `INR 100` is added into the cart. If you don't intend to have shipping in your cart read [this documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/free-shipping/) to set your shipping as free.

Which would then make.

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Subtotal | INR 1575 |
| Shipping | INR 0 (*This is 0 now*) |
| **TOTAL** | INR 1575 |

instead of

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Subtotal | INR 1575 |
| Shipping | INR 100 (*Removing this by free shipping*) |
| **TOTAL** | INR 1675 |